# Como puedo obtener un número con dos decimales cero (Ejem: 123.00) y que siga siendo tipo número

Tags: javascript, nodejs, float, numberformat

Mi problema es que cuando intento asignar el valor a una variable en JavaScript, al mostrarla le quita los decimales si estos son ceros

```
var test = 123.00;

console.log(test); // 123
```

Necesito obtener 123.00

¿Es posible?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la funcion `toFixed()`. Ejemplo:

```js
var test = 123.00;

console.log(test.toFixed(2));
```

Resultado:
`123.00`

Answer (score 0):

Si, según la [documentación de Mozilla Developer](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Number/toPrecision) deberás proceder así:

- Usar el constructor `Number`
- A este constructor le pasamos como argumento el valor numérico o la variable a tratar
- Le encadenamos el método `toPrecision`
- Dicho método recibe como argumento un enteró que implica la precisión de los dígitos que serán significativos de tomar en cuenta del argumento pasado a `Number`

Todo lo anterior nos devolverá una representación del número deseado pero como cadena de texto.

```
let numero = 123.00;
let nuevoNumero = Number(numero).toPrecision(5);

console.log(typeof nuevoNumero);
```